# compact embedding for Sobolev spaces

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

The Sobolev embedding  $H_{0, rad}^{1}(\Omega)  \hookrightarrow L^{p+1}(\Omega)$ is compact for all $p>1$ where $\Omega= \{x\in \mathbb R^N: 0<a<|x|<b\}.$

Is it possible to determine the best Sobolev constant of the embedding when $N \geq 2$.

Or is it possible to show that the $C_p>0$ is uniformly bounded below by a positive constant when $$\displaystyle\int_{\Omega } |\nabla u|^2 dx\geq C_p \displaystyle(\int_{\Omega }  |u|^{p+1} dx)^{2/p+1}; u\in H_{0, rad}^{1}(\Omega) .$$

Comment: I have a question about the notation. Is $H_{0,rad}^1(\Omega) $ the space of radial functions on $\Omega$? If not, I'm not seeing how the Sobolev embedding exists for all $p$ when $N >2$.

Comment: The embedding is true, as $0$ does not belong to $\Omega.$ Have a look at the book of M. Struwe "Variational Methods" fourth edition page 183.

Comment: I think I asked the question badly. I was trying to ask if we are assuming that $u$ is a radial function?

Comment: Yes, u is radial.

Comment: For radial functions you have $\|\nabla u\|_{L^2}$ bounds $\|u\|_{L^\infty}$ with some constant $C_\infty$. Interpolating with Poincare should tell you that the constants $C_p$ in your second question is uniform in $p$. (Do you mean uniformity in a different parameter?)

Answer (score 1):

Your first question seems hard to me. Using calculus of variations, we can probably find an ODE for $u$ (in terms of $r$) which maximizes the Sobolev constant. Maybe this will give you a closed form for the best constant, but it seems tricky.

However, your second question is true (at least when $a>0$). To see this, write $u = u(r ,\theta)$ where $\theta \in S^{N-1}$. Then we have the following estimates.

\begin{eqnarray} \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2  &= & \int_{S^{N-1}} \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)^2 r^{N-1} dr ~d\theta  \\
& = & Vol(S^{N-1}) \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)^2 r^{N-1} dr \\
&\geq & Vol(S^{N-1}) a^{N-1} \int_a^b \left( \frac{\partial u}{\partial r} \right)^2 dr  \\
& \geq & Vol(S^{N-1}) a^{N-1} \frac{ \|u\|_{L^\infty}^2 }{b-a}
\end{eqnarray}

From this, you can estimate all of the other $L^p$ norms as well.